# Can we have two aggregate count() functions in an only query?

Tags: mysql, sql

One company can have one or many offers
One offer has a number of jobs

So: companies <= offers <= numJobs

```
SELECT Count(t_offer.fkCompany) AS companies, 
       Count(t_offer.id) AS offers, 
       Sum(t_offer.nJobs) AS numJobs
FROM t_offer
```

For instance:

```
idOFFER    fkCOMPANY     numJOBS
   1           1            1
   2           3            2
   3           8            1
   4           1            2
```

The query should be:

*companies(3) <= offers(4) <= numJobs(6)*

but the result is:

*companies(4) <= offers(4) <= numJobs(6)*

**Is the only way to do this with more than one queries?**

Comment: Yes. Hint: They can be sub-queries

Comment: Yes you can and you can also use nested aggregated functions :)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want the number of *distinct* companies?

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT t_offer.fkCompany) AS companies, 
       Count(t_offer.id) AS offers, 
       Sum(t_offer.nJobs) AS numJobs
FROM t_offer
```

Comment: Yes, that is. But I'm doing it through access and it doesn't work, so... Maybe with an passthrouh query directly to MySQL.